# Error when using search text index in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 2 table using full text

```
test1(id, name1, description1)
test2(id, name2, description2, test1_id)
```

And a query

```
Select a.name1, b.name2 From test1 as a, test2 as b 
Where a.id = b.test_1id 
And MATCH(a.name1, a.description1, b.name2, b.desciption2) AGAINST ("%searchstring%")
```

Result is mysql can not run, I think error in `MATCH (...,b.name2, b.desciption2)`, How fix it ? thank you !!

Comment: let me know what you print `searchstring`

Comment: check my updated answer and let me know if problem still persist...

Comment: @FahimParkar: I has edited question, result not show, and error is in MATCH (...,b.name2, b.desciption2)

Comment: do you get something when you execute `Select a.name1, b.name2 From test1 as a, test2 as b 
Where a.id = b.test_1id` ??

Comment: also `a.id = b.test_1id` is INCORRECT... it should be `a.id = b.test1_id`

Answer (score 0):

isn't `AGAINST ("%searchstring%")` should be `AGAINST ('%searchstring%')`

Replace double quotes by single...

Below is the query that is generally used

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST ('PHP')
```

### Update 1

I see that you have problem at `Where a.id = b.test_1id`

I believe `Where a.id = b.test_1id` should be `Where a.id = b.test1_id`

In your query you have `test_1id` instead of `test1_id`. Check if this is your problem...

Good Luck!!!

Comment: The quotes don't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in the where condition:

Where a.id = **b.test_1.id** 
(b is the alias of table test2, but the field name shouldn't contain a dot)

Change that to the proper field name and it should work.